# Laravel: How to prevent users loading files from outside the base path

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel website and I have several routes that load the contents of images from Storage. I do this using the following code:

```
public function show_image($name) {
    echo Storage::disk('images')->get($name);
}
```

I want to prevent users being able to set name to something like ../../../error.log. So I don't want users to escape the Storage directory. I have a few ideas on how to accomplish this however I want to know is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just file name, not location, disallow them from inputting folder of any kind. Just cut the string on `/`.

```
end(preg_split("#/#", $name));
```

When you need to allow some folders and all of the contents, check the folder name, subfolder name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could either keep a registry/index of the uploaded images, and only allow the user to show a image from that registry (e.g. an `images` database table).

Or you could do a scan of the directory, that you are allowing files from, and make sure, that the requested file is in that list.

```php
public function show_image($name) {
    $files = Storage::disk('images')->files();
    if (! in_array($name, $files)) {
        throw new \Exception('Requested file not found');
    }

    echo Storage::disk('images')->get($name);
}
```

(code untested)